# Javascript: what does function(_) mean

Tags: javascript, function, bacon.js

I'm going through the bacon.js slide at:
http://raimohanska.github.io/bacon.js-slides/1.html

In the 1st line of the 2nd block, it says:

```
function always(value) { return function(_) { return value } }
```

what does `function(_)` mean?

Comment: `_` is simply a parameter in this context.

Comment: It’s not meaningful here, in JavaScript, but the convention is that `_` represents an ignored value.

Comment: @false Ironically "ignore this" did not work, and brought OP attention. I also have never heard about this convention. Interesting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In this case `_` is just a function parameter - a single underscore is a convention used by some programmers to indicate "ignore this binding/parameter".

Since JavaScript doesn't do parameter-count checking the parameter could have been omitted entirely. Such a "throw-away" identifier is found more commonly in other languages, but consider a case like `arr.forEach(function (_, i) {..})` where `_` indicates the first parameter is not to be used.

Comment: That makes at least some sense of it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: F# (and similar) do this consistently during pattern matching. C# can also do this for lambda variables. Its definitely common.. however useless it may be in the code you are reviewing.

Comment: I used this convention along with the Haskell type signatures in the slides. I prefer typesafe languages and tend to use some Haskell conventions in Javascript code too. Sorry for causing confusion!

Comment: but if it is not going to be used, why not just say function (i)={...}? is not the same?

Comment: @Victor It's a *convention*. The parameter might as as well be called `unused` or `thisParameterIsNotUsedUsed`.

Comment: yes I understand that it a convention for saying we are not using it, I just did not understand that sometimes we only need the iterator or index value (key) and in that case the callback function will require 2 parameters, the current value, and the index.

Answer (score 13):

It's an anonymous function with one argument, the name of that argument is `_`.

I don't know why they bother with the argument, since the function doesn't use it.

Comment: Upvoted to reverse the downvote, as I'm pretty sure that this answer is correct. The underscore becomes the name of the first argument. It is not used.

Comment: "Upvoted to reverse the downvote" - that's funny, but you're right there are many nervous people around :)

Comment: +1 for `I don't know why they bother with the argument, since the function doesn't use it.`

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as putting any other identifier to a list of arguments according to this document: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

You'll find in this doc that _ is a legal character that an identifier can start with.

There is no any meaning for this in your example, probably the author just thought that it's cooler than just ().